# How to set value in c:set attribute in jsp

Tags: hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

Can you advise me how to set value of my `c:set`.

I'm trying to set the value of `item[0]` to a bean property `id` in `TransactionAction` and send it to the controller class.

It gives me null when I print this value in controller class. However I'm able to view the value inside this JSP.

```
            <table>

                <tr><th>ID</th>
                    <th>LOGIN ID</th>
                    <th>LAST UPDATE BY</th>
                    <th>TRANSACTION TYPE</th>
                    <th>STATUS</th>
                </tr>    
                <c:forEach var="item" items="${ToDoList}">
                    <tr>
                        <td>${item[0]}</td>
                        <td>${item[1]}</td>
                        <td>${item[2]}</td>
                        <td>${item[3]}</td>   
                        <td>${item[4]}<td>

                        <td>
                            <c:set value = "item[0]" target="${transactionAction}" property="id" />

                            <form:select path="action" tabindex="50">

                        <form:option value="----------Please select---------" />
                        <form:option value="APPROVE" label="APPROVE" />
                        <form:option value="REJECT" label="REJECT"/> 
            </li>
        </form:select>
                    </tr>
                </c:forEach>

            </table>

        </c:if>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"> 

    </form:form>

</body>
</html>
```

Controller class to send the value of ToDoList to the above JSP

```
  public String adduser(LoginForm request,ModelMap map1) throws Exception {
    String currentUser = sessionUser.getUserName();
    System.out.println("========add user model ============================="+sessionUser.getUserName());
    String result = loginservice.adduser(request);
    List trx = loginservice.trxdetail(currentUser);
    map1.addAttribute("user", sessionUser.getUserName());
    map1.addAttribute("dateTime", sessionscopebillingdata.getDate());
    System.out.println("username from the controller class " + sessionUser.getUserName());        
    map1.addAttribute("ToDoList", trx);   
    map1.addAttribute("action",new TransactionAction());
    return "UserToDoList";
}
```

Below is my method to get the values from database using hibernate

```
public List trxdetail(String userName) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    Query query;
    query = session.getNamedQuery("Loginuser.findApprover");
    query.setString("loginId", userName.toUpperCase());
    Long ownerId = (Long) query.uniqueResult();
    Query qry = session.createQuery("select lu.id,lu.loginId,lu.lastUpdateBy,trx.transactionType,trx.status from Loginuser lu , BillingSolutionTrx trx where lu.id = ref_id and owner_Trx_Id='" + ownerId + "'");
    BillingSolutionTrx transactionDetail = new BillingSolutionTrx();
    List transactionList = qry.list();


    return transactionList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your model the object is called `action` not `transactionAction`.

Try to replace `target="${transactionAction}"` with `target="${action}"`

Comment: Hi thanks, after i changed to below I'm still getting null               <c:set value = "item[0]" target="${action}" property="id" />

Comment: You mean null on the controller side? Are you sure the value you expect is posted? Debug your posted request with firefox to know what you post.

Comment: yes getting null on the controller class . I have checked the values that I posted through debug but the value of item[0] is not included . Please advise

Comment: If you want to post this value, you have to set it in a form element, an input for exemple. Then it will be posted and you'll be able to retrieve it in you're controller;

Comment: Then what is the purpose of the below ,I thought the below line is to set value to by bean id , Please help to explain .                                    <c:set value = "item[0]" target="${action}" property="id"/>

Comment: I guess the scope of this action is only the page. Basically c:set set a value in a var. If you add target it set value in a existing bean instead of a new var. However, I could be wrong, I've never used the syntax with target.